# Evaluate this integral with exponential and error function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there any way to recast this integral to a solvable form?

$$\int^a_{-a} dY \; \exp[-b^2 Y^2] \; \text{Erf}\left[b \sqrt{1-Y^2}\right]$$

The integrand looks as though a trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution should work, but I can't get it to reduce further.

Use a change in variables and using the fact that the integrand is even, we get:

$$2 \int^c_{0} dY \; \exp[- Y^2] \; \text{Erf}\left[\sqrt{d^2-Y^2}\right]$$

Are there any identities that could be used from here?